# Can i add a port binding to a docker container while debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, debugging, .net-core, .net-5

I'm doing a PoC using dockers and .net 5. The idea is to create a console app or worker service that opens a TCP port and start listening for some specific traffic. If i test it outside of dockers it works but when i try to debug using dockers, the container is run without any port binding. Without the port binding the program does not receive any connection.

[image]

This happens with Background workers or Console Apps projects. Meanwhile i tried using the project "Container Application for Kubernetes" and removed all the web code and put mine own code. With this project, VS binds a random port to the exposed port.

[image]

Is there anyway i can add a port binding manually to a visual studio debugging process?

Answer (score 2):

When working on docker there are always 2 networks

1. host machine network
2. docker's own private network `docker network ls`

For a port mapping `--ports <left side>:<right side>` if you are debugging from withing docker container you'll have to use port on the right side of the mappings. If you are accessing from host machine use the one of the left hand side

Not sure if this is what you need.

I created a docker-compose with multiple port bindings, like so:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  consoleapp2:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}consoleapp2
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "8081:81"
      - "8082:82"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ConsoleApp2/Dockerfile
```

And this is what I see when I debug the app:

[image]

Comment: if not this then I probably didn't get the question

Answer (score 2):

You can also use container port 80 and then map it via the httpPort in launchSettings.json

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

...
```

launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "TerminalService": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "httpPort": 9003,
      "useSSL": false
    }
  }
}
```

This binds container port 80 to host port 9003.

Then in the code of my Worker I have a TCP listener listening on port 80:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 80);
```

Looks like you can also do it via DockerfileRunArguments in the project file (I did not test this):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DockerfileRunArguments>-p 8883:8883</DockerfileRunArguments>
</PropertyGroup>
```

See:
https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/206

Comment: Thanks for tip on DockerfileRunArguments, I can confirm this works.